# How does a consumer commit offsets in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, offset

I found an online quiz question:

How does a consumer commit offsets in Kafka?

1. It directly commits the offsets in Zookeeper
2. It interacts with the Group Coordinator broker
3. It directly sends a message to the __consumer_offsets topic

I choose 3. But the correct answer was 2. I don't understand why, as I thought that the job of the Group Coordinator is to receive heartbeats from all consumers of a consumer group and not deal with the consumer offset.

Can someone clear my misunderstanding and point me to some docs as I couldn't find something relevant on the net.

Answer (score 1):

The source code would be the best docs. But for consistency it's important that at the moment of commiting the offset, that consumer still has that partition assigned. The coordinator is the only one who knows this for sure.

You could also notice this when commiting to an offset that no longer belongs to the client.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinator of each group is chosen from the leaders of the internal offsets topic `__consumer_offsets`, which is used to store committed offsets.

This is mentioned in confluent documentation [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html#concepts) in third paragraph.
So option **2. It interacts with the Group Coordinator broker** is correct.